# I am getting this error while using nodemailer to send email notifications to a user

Tags: node.js, backend, nodemailer

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 142.251.175.109:587
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
errno: -4039,
code: 'ESOCKET',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '142.251.175.109',
port: 587,
command: 'CONN'
}

It is showing only this error and i am not understanding why is this happening.

Comment: Share with us your implementation. An please specify if you are using nodemailer within Intranet network or public like gmail?